# How to compute the following definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am having trouble calculating definite integrals of the form

[image]

In practice I have unknown real parameters within the exponentials and therefore am looking for a symbolic evaluation of the integrand. Here is the code

```
ϕ[α_, x_] := (Exp[α*x] - 1) / (Exp[α] - 1); 
u[x_, y_] := ϕ[α, x/(1 - y)]*(1 - y);
v[x_, y_] := ϕ[β, (1 - x - y)/(1 - x)]*(1 - x);
expr = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]* v[x, y];
Integrate[expr, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y}]
```

I would welcome any ideas!

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having with the *Mathematica* code you've written?  Please share that code.

Comment: The integral under consideration is an improper double integral having a singular set $y=1,0<x,x<1$ in view of `Limit[Exp[-x/(y - 1)]*(-1 + Exp[1 + y/(x - 1)])*(-1 + 
    x)*(x^2 + (y - 1)^2)/(-1 + y)^3, y -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow",
  Assumptions -> x > 0 && x < 1]` which results in `DirectedInfinity[-1+E^(x/(-1+x))]`  and `Reduce[E^(1 + 1/(-1 + x)) < 1 && x > 0 && x < 1, x]` which results in `0 < x < 1`. It's unclear whether the integral converges.

Comment: @user64494, the integral has no singularity, since for y -> 1 integration goes not over the full range 0<x<1, but only for x -> 0, where the limit is 1. Express the integration area with Boole `Limit[Boole[0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= x <= 1 - y]*
  Exp[-x/(y - 1)]*(-1 + Exp[1 + y/(x - 1)])*(-1 + 
    x)*(x^2 + (y - 1)^2)/(-1 + y)^3, y -> 1, Direction -> 1] `

Answer (score 1):

`Plot3D` shows a "smooth" integrand without singularity

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x/(y - 1)]*(-1 + Exp[1 + y/(x - 1)])*(-1 +x)*(x^2 + (y - 1)^2)/(-1 + y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y},AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

`Nintegrate` evaluates the integral without problems(error messages)

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x/(y - 1)]*(-1 + Exp[1 + y/(x - 1)])*(-1 +x)*(x^2 + (y - 1)^2)/(-1 + y)^3, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y}]
(*0.587283*)
```

**Answer to the modified question**

```
int[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[-((E^((x \[Alpha])/(1 - y)) (-1 + E^(((-1 + x + y) \[Beta])/(-1 + x))) (-1 +x) (x^2 + (-1 + y)^2) \[Alpha]^2)/((-1 + E^\[Alpha]) (-1 + E^\[Beta]) (-1 + y)^3))
, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1 - y}]
```

example

```
int[10, 5]
(*-0.125331*)
```

Comment: Right, the integrand is smooth. Numerical evaluation works as expected. the integral I posted is a simplified version. I have unknown real parameters within the exponentials and therefore am looking for a symbolic evaluation of the integrand. Maybe the integral is too complicated and it can't be done?

Comment: You don't need  necessaryly symbolic integration. Define something like `int["para"_?NumericQ]:= NIntegrate[ f[x,y,para],...]`

Comment: Indeed. I could probably do that and tabulate the results. The integral should converge for values of `alpha` and `beta` going to infinity

Comment: @RenéHiemstra No you don't have to tabulate the result, you might use the function `int[…]` like any other build in function!

Comment: @RenéHiemstra See my modified answer!

Comment: That's great! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!